# XG transaction isolation fails during test that generates unique sequence number (Objectify4)

Tags: multithreading, google-app-engine, transactions, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I have to generate a unique invoice number in a XG transaction that includes the following **3 entity groups** in my data model :

- (toplevel) ContactRoot <-- (ancestor) <--- **Contact** : contact must be updated to status Client during the transaction
- (toplevel) **CustomerSettings** : holds the next sequence number to use; there is one and only one instance of the CustomerSettings with a fixed, static ID; the sequence number must be increased +1 during the transaction
- (toplevel) InvoiceRoot <-- (ancestor) <--- **Invoice** : assign new unique invoice number based on the sequence number in CustomerSettings;

This is the essential part of the DAO implementation (irrelevant business rules checks etc removed) :

```
public void saveInvoice(final Invoice invoice) throws BusinessRuleException {

    final Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.factory().begin().cache(true);
    ofy.transact(new Work<Void>() {

        @Override
        public Void run() {
            CustomerSettings customerSettings = ofy.load()
                    .key(Key.create(CustomerSettings.class, CustomerSettings.ID)).safeGet();
            Contact contact = ofy.load().key(createContactKey(invoice.getContactId()).safeGet();
            contact.setContactType(ContactType.CLIENT);
            ofy.save().entity(contact).now();
            String invoiceNumber = generateSequence(ofy, customerSettings);
            invoice.setInvoiceNumber(invoiceNumber);
            ofy.save().entity(invoice).now();
            return null;
        }
    });
}
```

And the simplified version to generate the next sequence number where the next sequence number is increased for the next call and the CustomerSettings must be transactionally updated (I have this synchronized but I guess that is not really useful)
 :

```
private synchronized String generateSequence(Objectify ofy, CustomerSettings settings) {
    String ret = "";
    int sequence = settings.getNextSequence();
    settings.setNextSequence(sequence + 1);
    ofy.save().entity(settings).now();
    ret = "" + sequence;
    return ret;
}
```

This is what my unit test looks like for a **variable thread count** :

```
private void test(final int threadCount) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    final Environment currentEnvironment = ApiProxy.getCurrentEnvironment();
    Callable<String> task = new Callable<String>() {
        @Override
        public String call() {
            ApiProxy.setEnvironmentForCurrentThread(currentEnvironment);
            return generateInvoiceNumber();
        }
    };
    List<Callable<String>> tasks = Collections.nCopies(threadCount, task);
    ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
    List<Future<String>> futures = executorService.invokeAll(tasks);
    List<String> resultList = new ArrayList<String>(futures.size());
    // Check for exceptions
    for (Future<String> future : futures) {
        // Throws an exception if an exception was thrown by the task.
        resultList.add(future.get());
    }
    // Validate the IDs
    Assert.assertEquals(futures.size(), threadCount);
    List<String> expectedList = new ArrayList<String>(threadCount);
    for (long i = 1; i <= threadCount; i++) {
        expectedList.add("" + i);
    }
    Collections.sort(resultList);
    Assert.assertEquals(expectedList, resultList);
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private String generateInvoiceNumber() {
    InvoiceDAO invoiceDAO = new InvoiceDAO();
    Invoice invoice = ... create a valid invoice
    invoiceDAO.saveInvoice(invoice);
    log.info("generated invoice number : " + invoice.getInvoiceNumber());
    return invoice.getInvoiceNumber();
}
```

for instance when I run this with 32 threads simultaneous :

```
@Test
public void test32() throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
    test(32);
}
```

**But subsequent threads do not see that a previous transaction increased the invoice number sequence.**

This is the result :

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24,
>   25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32]> but was:<[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
>   1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3,
>   3]>

I went through the docs already a couple of times, can't figure out why this is not working ?

> If you access more than one entity group in a transaction, the
>   transaction with be an XG transaction. If you do access only one, it
>   is not. The standard limit of 5 EGs applies to all transactions.
>   [objectify transactions documentation](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Transactions)

what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: added more info in the google group for objectify : https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/7RWkC4DX6E0

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using the Datastore to generate the next invoice number as an Entity id?  Do you have some requirement that the id's be "old-id + 1"?  If you could relax that requirement, you could get rid of #generateSequence entirely.

Comment: yes, they are invoice numbers, legal requirement to be sequential;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code make the code not transactional :

> final Objectify ofy =
>   ObjectifyService.factory().begin().cache(true);
>
> ```
> ofy.transact(new Work<Void>() {
>
>        ....
>        ofy.save().entity(settings).now();   
>        ....
> ```
>
> }

because I reuse the objectify instance that is not transactional. To get the instance inside the transaction Work, you must always ask the instance like this :

> ObjectifyService.ofy()

more info in the group discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/objectify-appengine/7RWkC4DX6E0).

Looking at the implementation of `ObjectifyService`, you can see that new instances are pushed/popped onto/from a stack;

Apart from that, the test case is still not running .. the best way to test is presumably firing http requests simulataneous;